Using tSQLt to test view that uses CHECK OPTION
I am trying to create unit tests for a view that uses the WITH CHECK OPTION statement.  When I try to set SetFakeViewOn I get an error saying:
Cannot create trigger 'ViewNameHere_SetFakeViewOn' on view 'ViewNameHere' because the view is defined with CHECK OPTION.

What approach can be done to isolate the view using tSQLt?

Does this article help? It says that SetFakeViewOn causes schema changes which kinda defeat the point of "unit testing" a database (...to that that's even possible). If I were designing tests for a system using an updatable-view I imagine I'd have to hand-roll it all, you may have to as well.

@Dai what do you mean by "hand-roll"?

I mean I'd implement the test without using SetFakeViewOn and instead would need to run some hand-written T-SQL script to accomplish the same thing without any assistance from tsqlt.

@silverbullettruck2001 are you trying to test the view or fake the view (because you're trying to test something that uses the view)?
